# Adding image to GUI without using Swing? Java

Tags: java, image, graphics, awt, frame

Not sure if it is possible because everywhere I see this question being asked, the answer always involves using swing. But what about when you are extending Frame? Is it possible to add images to the GUI?

Comment: *"But what about when you are extending Frame? Is it possible to add images to the GUI?"*  Yes.  Yes it is.  The interesting question is: Why are you using an obsolete GUI component toolkit?

Comment: This question begs another question: Why are you extending `java.awt.Frame`? While Swing may be 4 yrs out of date, AWT is 20 years out of date -- why use it?

Comment: So, instead of using the defacto UI kit for the last 15+ years, you want to use the one it replaced?  Have you considered using JavaFX?  But before we could answer any of that, why do you not want to use Swing?

Comment: Because the current project I am working on must extend Frame. I did not anticipate I would have to import images.

Comment: A bit silly, I know.

Comment: *"Because the current project I am working on must extend Frame."*  Why must it extend frame?  (And if you're about to reply "that's what the customer ordered" ask *them* 'Why?'.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question as @AndrewThompson. Why all the secrecy? Please tell us the details if you want a decent answer.

Comment: Basically, you will need to create a custom component and paint the image - AFAIK :P

Comment: @AndrewThompson Because it is what we have been using in class for what ever reason. I am making a netflix - like program and so instead of just having rectangles filled with names of movies, I would like to add images.

Comment: OK, that's a decent reply. Well @MadProgrammer has your answer. I'm going to remove the Swing tag and replace it with an AWT tag.

Comment: *"Because it is what we have been using in class for what ever reason."*  Sack that teacher!  I suggest you use Swing with the system Look and Feel.  I'll bet the teacher neither notices nor comments.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So there is no way of importing a .jpg from my files into the program somehow?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would do that, but this project is due in 4 hours, and I just need to touch it up nice rather than change the whole thing. ha.

Comment: John, @MadProgrammer never said that there was "no way...", just create a BufferedImage from your File or resource and draw it in a Canvas's `paint` method.

Comment: @John Loading the images, easy, see [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html). Showing the images, harder, as I don't think AWT has a "default" UI component capable of rendering images.  You will need to start with something like [`Panel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Panel.html) or [`Canvas`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) or [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)

Comment: @John And override their `paint` method and paint the image yourself...

Comment: @MadProgrammer My apologies, I misinterpreted what you commented earlier. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Swing then use AWT (on top of my head from 15 years memory):

```
Frame frame=new Frame("Your Image");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("you.jpg"));
frame.add(img);
```